# How to convert array into 64bit Double Mac Absolute Time using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, macos, time, binary

Is it possible to convert Array having binary or hex values stored as each element into 64bit Double Mac Absolute Time?
When I inspect array using `p var_bytes` console shows following output.

```
\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\234\225x\266A\000\000\000\345\005\230\264
```

Is it possible to convert above array elements in 64bit Double Mac Absolute Time as a string?

My code is following just a simple `do..end`

```
puts "\nClose off the page header#{y.unpack("n")}\n"
            z.scan(/(.{8})(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{8})(.{8})(.{8})(.*\w)/m).each do |j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s|
                puts "\nContent1#{j.unpack("n")}\n"
                puts "\nContent2:#{k.unpack("n")}\n"
                puts "\nContent3:#{l.unpack("n")}\n"
                puts "\nContent4:#{m.unpack("n")}\n"
                puts "\nContent5:#{n.unpack("n")}\n"
                puts "\nContent6:#{o.unpack("n")}\n"
                puts "\nContent7:#{p.unpack("n")}\n"
                expdt = Time.at((q.unpack("L"))[0])
                createdt = Time.at((r.unpack("L"))[0])
                puts "Date1:\n#{expdt}\n"
                puts "\nDate2:\n#{createdt}\n"
                puts "\nCookie:\n"
                puts s.split(/\0/m)
            end
        end
```

what will the simple way to convert this negative values to positive so Time.at wont give error and then convert it according to MAC Epoch time?

Comment: What's in the array (ie what do those bytes represent) ?

Comment: I am not even sure what `64bit Double Mac Absolute Time` is. Can you also provide a link explaining what's that.  Otherwise I agree with @FrederickCheung: we need explanaition of what is stored in the array.

Comment: Most recent mac apis store dates as a double indicating number of seconds since the epoch (1st jan 2001 I think)

Comment: Bytes are in binary I can provide hex values 00 00 9C 95 78 B6 41 00 00 00 E5 05 98 B4 41 6E also link is here explaining what is MAC time . http://linuxsleuthing.blogspot.in/2011/02/calculating-embedded-os-x-times.html

Comment: The number of bits you provide are a lot more than 64. You provide 16 bytes, which sums to 128 bits. What kind of representation is that for a 64 bit Mac time? Can you explain a bit further

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
MAC_EPOCH = Time.gm(2001,1,1)

def bin2time(bin)
    return MAC_EPOCH + (bin.unpack "D")[0]
end
```

where `bin` is an 8-byte representation of a double precision float.

you may need to change "D" to "E" or "G" depending on where you are getting your data from.
check the [`unpack`](http://railsapi.com/doc/ruby-v1.9.2/classes/String.html#M000811) docs for details.

Comment: I am getting this converted time but what I should do so I can get this time as per MAC epoch time which starts from 01/01/2001 00:00:00. Also I am not able to use this method provided I have tried to do this Time.at function directly but any idea how can I convert this negative value to positive that I receive from unpacking with D,E or G.I guess I need to convert this array to some single value or a[0] will work? I did like this for my first array chunk `expdt = Time.at((q.unpack("G"))[0])` and it worked but for second chunk it gives me error time must be positive

Comment: I am not using any class or methods at this moment, I am editing my question and my code is there for you

Comment: It still causes trouble as I unpack it with D,E,G it unpacks with negative value sometimes so which would be the best option to convert addition of `MAC_EPOCH + (bin.unpack "D")[0] time`. I have tried with `.to_i(16)` but at some point time range exceeds so I get error.

Comment: Negative time values are simply times before 01/01/2001.