# How to change default Epoch time for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, time, epoch

I want to change default epoch time that Ruby is using to 1-1-2001 UTC as it is default OS X epoch time. Is this possible?

I have got some hint from answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052298/how-to-convert-array-into-64bit-double-mac-absolute-time-using-ruby) but I am still not able to get proper out put and sometimes time goes out of range due to conversion type I use for unpacking I have tried by unpacking with all formats including D,E,G,Q,V,v,q,e,L,l and others as well.

But at some point my values go out of the range. Is there any way to force ruby to start epoch as user defined? Many times I get this error:

```
fileread.rb:48:in `at': 822752480099018910000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 out of Time range (RangeError)
```

Comment: Why does the epoch need to be changed? Also, I'm pretty sure the epoch on Mac OS X is 1-1-1970.

Comment: @JohnDouthat Some weird places use that different epoch. I don't know where it occurs in OS X, but I know iOS uses it for some things like iMessage timestamps (but regular text messages use the Unix epoch).